# Каждое число в выражении сделайте переменной

Tags: javascript

1. Дано такое выражение: (5 + 7) / ((12 - 5.5) * (5 - 8 * 12)). Рассчитайте на JavaScript и выведите результат на страницу.
2. Каждое число в выражении сделайте переменной, например, var x = 5; var y = 7 и так далее. При этом если число «5» встречается дважды, то не надо создавать вторую переменную.
3. Подставьте в выражение вместо цифр переменные, посмотрите на результат и убедитесь, что он совпадает с рассчитанным в 1-м пункте.

Первый пункт сделал, требуется помощь со 2 и 3 пунктом, как правильно реализовать благодаря переменным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам просто нужно разбить выражение на переменные:

```js
// так как значение 5 повторяется несколько раз,
// переменную нужно переиспользовать,
// а не определять вторую подобную
const a = 5;
const b = 5.5;
const c = 7;
const d = 8;
const e = 12

const result = (a + c) / ((e - b) * (a - d * e));
```

Comment: Благодарю, я почему-то делал как на примере

var a = 5
var b = 7 и т.д.

Comment: var - это тоже способ создать переменную, но так сказать устаревший. [const и let](https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const) - это современный способ определения переменных. Если ответ помог, не забудьте поставить галочку слева по рейтингом ответа.

Comment: да, я читал эту статью, но видимо придется еще разов 5-10 перечитать, чтобы закрепить материал (не внимательный одним словом)

спасибо за помощь)

p.s поставил)